# excess the limit of random numbers in java?

Tags: java

I am actually working on a jackpot game where it generates random numbers and asks user to guess the random number, if it meets the criteria it prints **win** and if not it moves to other conditional statements.

I have almost finished writing my code and just I got confused on this step. My query is:

I have set a limit a on `randInt(max)` i.e random numbers but I want to know that if it exceeds its limit, it must show a message which I can't help myself out.

Please share your ideas if anyone can.

```
public class Jackpot {

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int mode; 
    System.out.println("Choose the difficulty level mode");
    System.out.println("1: Easy (0-15)");
    System.out.println("2: Medium (0-30)");
    System.out.println("3: Difficult (0-50)");
    System.out.println("or type another number to quit");
    mode = input.nextInt();
    if(mode == 1){
        Start_Game(randInt(15));
    }else if(mode == 2){
        Start_Game(randInt(30));
    }else if(mode == 3){
        Start_Game(randInt(50));
    }else if(mode <= 4 || mode >= 0){
        System.out.println("Quit");
        Restart_Game();
    }    
}
public static int randInt(int max){
    int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * ((max) + 1));

    return randomNum;
}
 public static int Start_Game(int max){  
    System.out.println("Please enter your guessed number");
    int GuessNum , life = 5;; 

    do{
        GuessNum = input.nextInt();

         if(GuessNum == max){
            System.out.println("You WIN");
            break;
        }else if(GuessNum > max){
            System.out.println("BIG");
            life--;
            System.out.println("life: " + life);
        }else if(GuessNum < max){
            System.out.println("SMALL");            
            life--;
            System.out.println("life: " + life);
        }

    }while(life != 0);
    Restart_Game();
    return 0;
}
public static void Restart_Game(){
    System.out.println("if you want to restart the game \nPress Y to continue or N to exit");
    char restart = input.next().charAt(0);
    if(restart == 'Y' || restart == 'y'){
        //Start_Game(randInt(10));
        int mode; 
        System.out.println("Choose the difficulty level mode");
        System.out.println("1: Easy (0-15)");
        System.out.println("2: Medium (0-30)");
        System.out.println("3: Difficult (0-50)");
        System.out.println("or type another number to quit");
        mode = input.nextInt();
        if(mode == 1){
            Start_Game(randInt(15));

        }else if(mode == 2){
            Start_Game(randInt(30));
        }else if(mode == 3){
            Start_Game(randInt(50));
        }else if(mode <= 4 || mode >= 0){
            System.out.println("Quit");
            Restart_Game();
        }
    } else if(restart == 'n'|| restart == 'N'){
        System.out.println("Thank you for playing");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private static int randIt(int max) {
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

Comment: you mean to validate the user input ??#

Comment: i mean that if i am choosing 1 so the limit is 15 so if i type 16 it should give me error and same for others.

Comment: Well, the problem is that the parameter in `Start_Game` is not really the `max` but the value to find. Pass the `max` value instead of `randInt(max)`. And in the method, generate the `int value = randInt(max)`. You now have the `value` to found and the `max` value accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your "Game" don't have a clue of the actual range, even if you have a parameter call "max", it is only the value to found, you could renamed it or you could really send the maximum value accepted :

```
Start_Game(15);
```

And let the game generate a random value based on that. You have the `max` value and the `random value` to found. Easy to check your case now.

```
public static int Start_Game(int max){  
    int toFind = randInt(max);

    do{
        GuessNum = input.nextInt();

        if(GuessNum > max){
            System.out.println("Out of range");
        } else if(GuessNum == toFind ){
            System.out.println("You WIN");
            break;
        }else if(GuessNum > toFind ){
            System.out.println("BIG");
            life--;
            System.out.println("life: " + life);
        }else if(GuessNum < toFind ){
            System.out.println("SMALL");            
            life--;
            System.out.println("life: " + life);
        }

    }while(life != 0);
}
```

Note : You should rename your method and variable, JAVA has a convention (like other language), don't name a variable starting with a uppercase for instance.

```
public static int startGame(int max){
```

or

```
int guessNum;
```